# C compiler errors on TUN/TAP

Tags: c++, c, linux, tun

I like to create a TUN/TAP interface out of a C++ program. I found a straight foward tutorial on the net at
http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/.

The problem is, that I seem to have linking problems with with if.h and if_tun.h.
When I strip the tutorial to the minimal example below, only to open a slot, I get a number of errors.
Example:

```
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
int main(void){
char *clonedev = "/dev/net/tun";
open(clonedev,O_RDWR);
return 0;
}
```

If think this *should* compile, yet I get the following errors:

```
/usr/include/linux/if.h:184:19: error: field 'ifru_addr' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:185:19: error: field 'ifru_dstaddr' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:186:19: error: field 'ifru_broadaddr' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:187:19: error: field 'ifru_netmask' has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:188:20: error: field 'ifru_hwaddr' has incomplete type
tuntap.cpp: In function 'int main()':
tuntap.cpp:6:18: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
tuntap.cpp:7:15: error: 'O_RDWR' was not declared in this scope
tuntap.cpp:7:21: error: 'open' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm using GCC 4.7.2 (in this case, from the command line without any switches) on Fedora 18 with Linux 3.11.4.
What's wrong with my libraries?

Comment: Tried both (gcc and .c file extension as well as g++ and .cpp file extension) with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a different include.  Use ...

```
#include <net/if.h>
```

... instead of ...

```
#include <linux/if.h>
```

In addition, include another file.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Comment: That solved half of it (the incomplete types), thanks.
The compiler still doesn't recognize 0_RDWR and open(). The funny thing is, when coding with eclipse, the syntax highlighter _does_ recognize it and tells the correct arguments to use.

Comment: @Marste : See updated answer.  You really should select just *one* language to work with, either C or C++.  You need to learn to find your program's dependencies.  At the source level it will be includes, but you will also encounter shared objects and libraries when it's time to link.  Knowing where all the parts come from and when they are needed will be critical to becoming an efficient programmer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it.
I'm programming the whole project in C++, I was just thinking that it makes no difference in that particular case.
But you're right and as you have aparently noticed,  programming is not my bread-and-butter job (I'm a networks guy), so there's much to get used to.